# How to use decltype to get vector element's type as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, decltype, template-argument-deduction

Here is part of my code:

```
int getLength(const vector<int> &arr) {
    auto  n=arr.size(),dis=n;
    unordered_map<int,decltype(dis)> S;
    //...
}
```

So far so good. Now instead of hardcoded "`int`" for my `std::unordered_map`, I tried to change it to something like:
    `unordered_map<decltype(arr.front()),decltype(dis)> S;`
or
    `unordered_map<decltype(arr)::value_type,decltype(dis)> S;`
or
    `unordered_map<decltype(arr[0]),decltype(dis)> S;`

None seems to work. What would be the right grammar to use `decltype()` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the right grammar to use decltype here?

`decltype(arr.front())` and `decltype(arr[0])` are all OK but, unfortunately, all of they returning a **reference** to a **const** `int` (considering that `arr` is a constant vector)

You have to remove the reference and the const so, by example

```
std::unordered_map<
      std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arr.front())>>,
      decltype(dis)> S;
```

Using the `::value_type` is better (IMHO) because you avoid the constness, so you have to remove only the reference, so you can write

```
   std::unordered_map<
      std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arr)>::value_type,
      decltype(dis)> S;
```